# Pasar ComboBox a Input

Tags: php, javascript, combobox

Tengo un `ComboBox` que cuando lo selecciono quiero que me pase el dato a un `Input`

Es decir, lo que quiero conseguir, es cuando seleccione la `Select`este pinte a su vez en el `Input`el dato que le corresponda de la consulta que esta realizando a la `BBDD`

El `código es`

`Iniciador`del `ComboBox`

```
                <th style="text-align:left;">Código del pedido</th>
            <td>
              <select  style="width:218%" class="form-control" name="codigo" id="codigo" onchange="change_documento();  change_documento1(); change_documento2(); change_documento3(); change_documento4(); change_documento5()" required>
                <option value=""><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('codigo') : ''; ?> </option>    
                <?php
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', 'prueba', 'prueba');
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select distinct puo from puo order by puo');
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                  ?>
                  echo <option value="<?php echo $row['puo']; ?>"><?php echo $row['puo']; ?> </option>
                  <?php }
                  ?>

                </select> 
              </td>
```

Función `JavaScript`

```
   function change_documento()
{
var codigo = $("#codigo").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "subcategoria.php",
  data: "codigo=" + codigo,
  cache: false,
  success: function (response)
  {
                      //alert(response);return false;
                      $("#producto_servicio1").html(response);
                    }
                  });
}
```

Archivo `subcategoria.php`

```
<?php
include('dbConfig.php');
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$sql= "select producto_servicio from puo where puo='$codigo' order by producto_servicio";
$query = $db->query($sql);

while($res = $query->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<option  value="'.$res['producto_servicio'].'">'.$res['producto_servicio'].'</option>'  ; 
}

?>
```

`Input`que recibe el dato

```
     <th style="text-align:left;">Nombre del Pedido</th>
        <td>
           <input type="text" style="width:218%" class="form-control" name="producto_servicio1" id="producto_servicio1" disabled onchange="change_documento();"
                  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('producto_servicio1') : ''; ?>" />
            </td>
```

Comment: Hola Alberto. Y qué problema tienes? No te funciona, el resultado no es el esperado, te da errores en consola...?

Comment: Solo, que se queda en blanco, no pinta nada ni da error en la consola, si lo hago funcionar el input que recoge el dato como un select option si funciona, pero no quiero que sea un select quiero que sea un Input

Comment: Añade esa explicación a la pregunta. Necesitamos más datos. Puedes hacer algun tipo de log para ver donde puede estar el error?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que estás intentado cargar en el *AJAX* ? ¿El *input* solo es cargado cuando se realiza un cambio en el *select*?

Comment: Claro, cuando haga realice un cambio en la select este debe de cargar el dato de la BBDD en el input

Comment: Puedes añadir un ejemplo de lo que recibe el *ajax*, por lo que veo le envías un elemento `<option>`

Comment: Supongo que en el `subcategoria.php`debo de enviar un `input` en vez de un `option`

Comment: Si es eso el problema, Te voy a añadir una respuesta vale ;). No no tienes que añadirle el input. Déjame  un segundo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el **subcategoria.php**

```
    <?php
    include('dbConfig.php');
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $sql= "select producto_servicio from puo where puo='$codigo' order by producto_servicio";
    $query = $db->query($sql);

    while($res = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $res['producto_servicio']; 
    }

    ?>
```

En tu **JavaScript**

```
   function change_documento()
{
var codigo = $("#codigo select").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "subcategoria.php",
  data: {codigo:codigo},
  cache: false,
  success: function (response)
  {
                      //alert(response);return false;
                      $("#producto_servicio1").val(response);
                    }
                  });
}
```

**Input** que recibe el dato

> Aquí sinceramente no sé que quieres realizar en el value pero con
>   dejarlo vacio vale. La función **onchange** no le haría falta ya que es
>   llamada por el **ComboBox**

```
<th style="text-align:left;">Nombre del Pedido</th>
    <td>
       <input type="text" style="width:218%" class="form-control" name="producto_servicio1" id="producto_servicio1" disabled
              value="" />
        </td>
```

Comment: Voy a ver, pero no recoge la variable código pero por lo demas parece que funciona voy a ver si fuera por error de sintaxis.

`<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: codigo in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\puo\vista\Tablas\facturas\subcategoria.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />`

Comment: En el AJAX estaba puesto `var codigo = $("#codigo select").val();`y es `var codigo = $("#codigo").val();` tonto de mi que no me di cuenta, muchisimas gracias por la ayuda ^^

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por que `{codigo:codigo},`en vez de ` data: "codigo=" + codigo,`

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés, `var codigo = $("#codigo select").val();` debería recoger el valor del campo seleccionado en el *comboBox*. Por otro lado, lo que le pasamos a data es un *array* de datos. **`{codigo:codigo}`** lo que define es un elemento donde el primer valor es la **key** (clave) y el segundo valor el *value* para recuperarlo en este caso desde el *php* por la variable definida **$_POST["key"]**. La forma que le estabas pasando también es correcta, pero tendrías que añadirle *{ }* `data: "{'data1':'" + value1+ "', 'data2':'" + value2+"'}",`